# Cannot coerce a:array to an a:object in mule dataweave

Tags: dataweave

I am trying to map for multiple `SalesOrderLine` but getting an error as cannot coerce an array to an object.below is my code..

```
payload.ORDERS05.*IDOC.E1EDP01 map 
{(

    ns1#SalesOrderCRM: {
    ns0#SalesOrderHeader: {
        ns0#SalesOrderIDs: {
            ns2#ID: payload.ORDERS05.IDOC.E1CUCFG.E1CUPRT.PARENT_ID
        },
        ns0#CustomerParty: {
            ns3#CustomerPartyIDs: {
                ns2#ID: payload.ORDERS05.*IDOC.E1EDP01.E1EDPA1.PARTN[$$]
            },
            ns3#Description: payload.ORDERS05.*IDOC.E1EDP01.E1EDPA1.PARGE[$$],
            ns3#Status: payload.ORDERS05.IDOC.EDI_DC40.STATUS
        }
    },

    ns0#SalesOrderLine: {
        ns0#Description: payload.ORDERS05.*IDOC.E1EDP01.ABGRT[$$],
        ns0#Quantity: payload.ORDERS05.*IDOC.E1EDP01.MENGE[$$],
        ns0#LineNumberID: payload.ORDERS05.*IDOC.E1EDP01.E1EDP20.WMENG[$$],
        ns0#UnitPrice: payload.ORDERS05.*IDOC.E1EDP01.PREIS[$$]
   }
})
}
```

Please suggest solution for it.

Comment: We need more information to go off of. What does your input payload look like? Does your error show any line information or code fragment?

Comment: hey @ChadGorshing my input and output payload is of xml type.It shows me error on my first line.i.e payload.ORDERS05.*IDOC.E1EDP01 map for cannot coerce an array to an object..my root element is salesOrderCRM

Answer (score 4):

The [`map`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/dataweave-operators#map) operator returns an `:array`, and [XML output](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/dataweave-formats#xml) requires only objects.  The `{( ... )}` syntax converts an array of objects to an object that contains each key value pair (tuple) contained in those objects.

To get past the error you see in the editor, try putting the whole expression within the `{( )}` nested braces, and see what you get afterward.

Remember that to produce XML, you must output only objects, and that those objects can have more than one key/value pair with the same key. This corresponds to XML nodes.  While debugging, it's often handly to change your output to java, and see what you're working with, like so:

```
%output application/java
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Giving the key to this - payload.ORDERS05.*IDOC.E....
like 
key1 :payload.ORDERS05.*IDOC.E .....